# Probability of identical coin selection

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You have two bags of $w_1$ and $w_2$ number of coins with face value from $1$ to $n$ and each coin occurring at most once in each bag (example $1$ can occur in both bags but not in same bag twice).

What is the probability that there are $w$ common coins?

Comment: Are we to assume each bag is a random sample of different coins, with each equally likely?  In anything resembling real life, this is not likely: there are lots more (US or Canadian) 25 than 50 cent pieces in circulation.

Answer (score 2):

The probability that there are w pairs of commons coins in the two bags would be:$${w_1\choose w}*{n-w_1\choose {w_2-w}}\over{n \choose w_2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Count the ways to select $w$ coins common to bag-1 and $w_2-w$ uncommon coins to fill the second bag, out of all the ways to select $w_2$ coins in the second bag.

Comment: Ninja'd by browngreen